# Writing to excel and read only property vb.net

Tags: .net, excel, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have created a form in Visual Studio 2013 which is used to enter data in Excel by multiple users at same time. It works perfectly fine except if two users open form at the same time or if one has clicked submit and the form is still processing, error occurs.

> Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

When writing data to file, I want to make it read only so that other users can wait. How do I do this?

```
Imports excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1
Dim xlapp As New excel.Application
Dim workbook As excel.Workbook
Dim worksheet As excel.Worksheet

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
workbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Open("\2.xlsx")
xlapp.Visible = False
worksheet = workbook.Sheets("sheet1")
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

If workbook.MultiUserEditing Then
    workbook.AcceptAllChanges()
    workbook.Save()
End If

Dim row As Long
Dim alpha As Long = 0
row = 5
With worksheet
    Do While .Cells(row, 4).value IsNot Nothing
        row = row + 1
    Loop

    .Cells(row, 2).value = Me.fname.Text
    .Cells(row, 3).value = Me.lname.Text
    Me.fullname.Text = Me.fname.Text + Me.lname.Text
    .Cells(row, 4).value = Me.fullname.Text

End With
xlapp.DisplayAlerts = False

workbook.SaveAs("\2.xlsx", AccessMode:=excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared)

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Have you considered making the Excel file a Template?

Comment: what does that mean? sorry I have little idea about all this

Comment: A template file is like a read only file. Example: When you open a regular excel file as you are with `workbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Open("\2.xlsx")` this opens the file and keeps it open until the user closes it. A Template on the other hand, will simply copy itself as a new file to the user “Document1” and close the template. Then when the user tries to save the file they will be prompted to give it a file name since the template is already closed. There is less chance of users grabbing the file at the same time then.

Comment: But I don't want users to be prompted for saving the file. The file should be saved automatically. They just need to enter data through the form.

Comment: Ok... So users enter data in the form and press a save button? Are they lined up one after another. Are they supposed to close the file? My point is how do you know when the user is finished so you can close the file? Users will not always cooperate here.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to simply grab the users input and then add it to the workbook yourself. This way the user never sees the workbook and only you are opening and closing the workbook to make the changes.

Comment: They won't be able to see the file. It's visible mode is set to false. They will just enter data in form and hit submit. Once they close the form, the file will close automatically without user knowing about it.

Comment: What if they forget to close the form?

Comment: The file will be open but they won't know about that. Although I don't think that will affect the populating of data into excel

Comment: Moreover, the form will be available in shared drive as an exe. So they can install it on their computers and then work on the form

Comment: Your code does not show where you are closing your file. You SaveAs, but I don't see where the file is closed, so technically when you exit this... the file is still open.

Comment: The users can enter data any number of times. What I mean is once they open the form, they can enter data 100 number of times without closing the form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128786/discussion-between-johng-and-user5538704).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is, file should be mutual exclusive for writing, i.e. if someone has opened it for writing others cannot open it for editing.
One easy solution to this problem is, whenever a user opens a file keep track of it. This you can achieve by tracking table in DB or by file system.

1. **For DB approach** :- Check if record exist for filename in table. If yes, set a label's text to "Read only" and do not allow save. If no record found, insert a record in DB and allow save to happen. Delete this record from table when form is saved/closed. Even you can extend the functionality by keeping track which user opened/closed it and at what time. In such case you don't need to delete the record but add more columns IsOpened, User, StartDateTime, EndDateTime.
2. **For file system approach** :- Check if empty file with `filename` exist in `Lock` folder. If file exists, set a label's text to "`Read only`" and do not allow save. If file does not exist, create an empty file with `filename` in `Lock` folder and allow save to happen. Delete this file from folder when form is saved/closed.

Updated For file system approach:-
Below is just to show you the approach. I have not compiled the code. Please excuse me on this.

1. Create a folder "Lock" at location where excel files will be saved.
2. Add an indicator (e.g. label lblAccess) on the form.
3. Update the Form1_Load() to check if file exist in Lock Folder and indicate user about access.
4. Update Button1_Click function to perform or not to perform save as

--- Code is below ---

```
Dim lockFile As String ' form/class level variable

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim filename As String = "2.xlsx"
    Dim sharedFolder As String = "\\ComputerABC\XL_FILE_FOLDER\LOCK\"

    lockFile = sharedFolder + filename
    If (System.IO.File.Exists(lockFile)) Then
        Me.lblAccess.Visible = True
        Me.lblAccess.Text = "Read-Only Access. Data cannot be saved."
    Else
        IO.File.Create(lockFile).Dispose() 'create empty file
        Me.lblAccess.Visible = False
    End If
    Me.Button1.Enabled = Not Me.lblAccess.Visible

    workbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Open("\" + filename)
    xlapp.Visible = False
    worksheet = workbook.Sheets("sheet1")
End Sub



Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    :
    :
    :
    If Not lblAccess.Visible Then
        workbook.SaveAs("\2.xlsx", AccessMode:=excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared)
        System.IO.File.Delete(lockFile)
        lockFile = ""
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I have to use the file system approach but can you please explain more as to how to code this?

Comment: The problem is that the users won't close the form after entering one data. They can enter any number of times with the form opened. So, the second time lock file is not being created and it shows an error. Moreover, if a user gets "Read-Only Access. Data cannot be saved.", then to check if file is free to write data, he has to close and open the form again which I don't want. There should be some limit after which the user gets to know that file is free and he can click submit. Please help on how to  do this?

Comment: Introduce a check and save option. For all "Read-Only Access. Data cannot be saved." users clicks on check and save button. It checks if lockfile exist, if not save the form data. For user who has write access (i.e. owner of lock file) remove the lockfile after allowed time (e.g. 15 min) and Inform the user to use check and save. File system has its own limitations that's why we had DB and later client server web hosting solutions.

Comment: Is using SyncLock will be beneficial?

Comment: SyncLock will not be useful for your scenario as the clients are running on multiple machines.

Comment: I added try-catch block around my code. But, now it shows "the file is locked. Try again later" or, "The file is opened by another user.Do you want to open it as read only" I don't want my users to see all this. It should just act as a normal form to enter data without showing these popup boxes. How do I rectify this?

Comment: For which file it says "the file is locked. Try again later"? With try catch, add finally and make sure file is closed in finally.